# partial equilibrium firm investment model with collateral constraints

Tags: investment, firm, financial-constraints

I am trying to solve the partial equilibrium firm investment model with collateral constraint. My state variables are firm productivity, capital and debt.
While I know how to iterate the value function and get an unconstrained solution.
I don't understand how to solve value function for cases when constraint binds.

Could someone suggest me how to deal with this?

Comment: Can you give a bit more info... maybe an outline of your model.